# How to get DOM element by using mouse pointing position in dart script?

Tags: dart

How to get DOM element by using mouse pointing position in dart script?
Did dart have any library for this?

Answer (score 3):

`Document` has a method [`elementFromPoint`](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/#dart-dom-html.HtmlDocument@id_elementFromPoint) which is supposed to do what you want, but I find that's it's not that useful in practice. Often times you have some elements obscuring the ones that you want to locate by mouse, or you need all the elements under a point, not just the top-most one.

I tend to roll my own logic to find an element, but you do have to be careful because an element is not always where it claims to be. CSS transforms in particular can throw things off.

Here's the basic idea though:

```dart
Iterable<Element> getElementsAt(Element container, Point p) =>
    container.children.where((c) => containsPoint(c.offset, p));

bool containsPoint(Rectangle r, Point p) =>
    r.left <= p.x && r.right >= p.x && r.top <= p.y && r.bottom >= p.y;
```

Answer (score 2):

From the mouse events (`onMouseDown`, `onMouseMove`, etc.) you get a `MouseEvent`. This `MouseEvent` has an attribute target that shows you the element under the mouse pointer. The code would look like that:

```dart
document.onMouseMove.listen((MouseEvent e) {
  Element target = e.target;
  print(target.id);
});
```